# Seed mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongoimport

I want to create replica set of 3 nodes using `docker-compose` and seed initial data to them. If I remove `--replSet` and seed data without specifying hosts I have no problems.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  master:
    image: 'mongo:3.4'
    ports:
      - '50000:27017'
    volumes:
      - './restaurants.json:/restaurants.json'
      - './setup.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00_setup.js'
      - './seed.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_seed.sh'
    command: '--replSet rs'

  slave1:
    image: 'mongo:3.4'
    ports:
      - '50001:27017'
    command: '--replSet rs'

  slave2:
    image: 'mongo:3.4'
    ports:
      - '50002:27017'
    command: '--replSet rs'
```

**seed.sh**

```
# ...
_wait "slave1"
_wait "slave2"
echo "Starting to import data..."
mongoimport --host="rs/master:27017,slave1:27017,slave2:27017" --db db --collection restaurants --drop --file /restaurants.json > /dev/null
echo "Done."
```

**Log**

```
master_1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01_seed.sh
master_1  | Waiting for slave1...
master_1  | .
master_1  | Done.
master_1  | Waiting for slave2...
master_1  | Done.
master_1  | Starting to import data...
master_1  | 2017-11-26T16:06:39.148+0000        [........................] db.restaurants       0B/11.3MB (0.0%)
master_1  | 2017-11-26T16:06:39.653+0000        [........................] db.restaurants       0B/11.3MB (0.0%)
master_1  | 2017-11-26T16:06:39.653+0000        Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
master_1  | 2017-11-26T16:06:39.653+0000        imported 0 documents
mongoreplication_master_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but i ran into the same issue recently, it's worth noting that the mongo `docker-entrypoint.sh` script will strip the `--replicaSet` argument during the initDb phase, see:

https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/3.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L237

So you can't connect to the host that is running the init scripts, you can create another container with the sole purpose of initializing the replicaset however and override the `docker-entrypoint.sh`